# misunderstanding of stalk of image equal to image of stalk

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $\mathscr{F}$ be a presheaf and let $\mathscr{F}^+$ be its sheafification, defined as follows:

$$\mathscr{F}^+(U) = \left\{(s_p) \in \prod_{p \in U}\mathscr{F}_p : (*)\right\}$$

where the condition $(*)$ says that for all $p \in U$ there is an open neighbourhood $V \subseteq U$ of $p$ and $t \in \mathscr{F}(V)$ such that $t_q = s_q$ for all $q \in V$ ($t_q$ is the germ of $t$).

Lemma:

Let:$\phi: F\to G$ be a homomorphism of abelian sheaves.The image  $Im\phi$ is defined as the sheafification of $(Im\phi)_{pre}$.
There is a proof online as follows.

Proof:let $t(x)\in Im (\phi_x)$ and pick an $s(x)\in F_x$ with $\phi _x(s(x))=t(x)$.This means that over some open neighbourhood $V$,one has $\phi_V (s)=t(x)$,and t is a section of $Im\phi$ over $V$.This shows that $Im\phi_x\subset (Im\phi)_x$.

The other way around, if $t$ is a section of $G$ over an open $U$ containing $x$ locally lying in image presheaf, the restriction $t\subset V$ lies in $Im\phi_{v}$ for some smaller neighbourhood $V$ of $x$,hence the germ $t(x)$ lies in $Im\phi_x$.

I don't get the second proof.  From the defintion of sheafification. In fact, I just read some textbook for a while, and I see many textbook definition of sheafification from different way, I want to use above definition to get the answer. First, I write down explictly by picture, since my computer always dead.
I think I get stuck to settle such multi- information of sheafification and direct limit.[image]

Can someone help me, I think I don't full understand the essence of the sheafification, and thus I can't see the last proof where it use the defintion of sheafification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea of sheafification is to create a sheaf whose stalks agree with the presheaf. More formally, we have the following theorem:

> Let $\mathscr{F}$ be a presheaf on a space $X$. Then the natural map $i:\mathscr F\to \mathscr F^+$ (sending $s\in \mathscr F(U)$ to $(s_p)\in \prod_{p\in U}\mathscr F_p$, where $s_p$ is the germ of $s$ at $p$) induces an isomorphism $i_x:\mathscr F_x\to \mathscr F^+_x$ for each $x\in X$. The inverse $j_x$ is given by sending the germ of $(s_p)\in \mathscr F^+(U)$ to $s_x$.

I'll give the proof later, but let's see how it applies to your situation first. It looks like you are trying to prove that for all $x$, $\operatorname{Im}\phi_x=(\operatorname{Im}\phi)_x$. There are two implicit identifications going on here:

- Using the theorem, we can identify $(\operatorname{Im}\phi)_x$ with $((\operatorname{Im}\phi)_\text{pre})_x$;
- $(\operatorname{Im}\phi)_\text{pre}$ includes into $\mathscr G$ over each open set. Maps of presheaves that are injective on each open set induces injections on each stalk, so we can identify $((\operatorname{Im}\phi)_\text{pre})_x$ with a subset of $\mathscr G_x$.

The second half of the proof can be rephrased as follows:

A general element of the right hand side is given by the germ of a $t\in(\operatorname{Im}\phi)(U) $  for some $U$ containing $x$. By the definition of sheafification, $t$ is locally of the form $i(s)$ (where $i$ is as in the theorem), meaning that for each $p\in U$, there is a neighbourhood $V\subseteq U$ of $p$ such that $t|_V=i_V(t')$ for some $t'\in (\operatorname{Im}\phi)_\text{pre}(V)=\operatorname{Im}\phi_V$. In particular, the germ of $t$ at $x$ is $i_x(t'_x)$ for some neighbourhood $V$ of $x$ and $t'\in \operatorname{Im}\phi_V$. Under the two identifications, $t_x$ is identified with the germ of $t'$ at $x$, viewed as a section of $\mathscr G$. If $t'=\phi_V(s)$, then $t'_x=\phi_x(s_x)\in \operatorname{Im}\phi_x$.

Now we prove the theorem:

$j_x$ is well-defined because if $(s_p)\in \mathscr F^+(U)$ and $(t_p)\in \mathscr F^+(V)$ have the same germ at $x$, then for some  $W\subseteq U\cap V$ containing $x$, $s_p=t_p$ for all $p\in W$. In particular, $s_x=t_x$.

For any neighbourhood $U$ of $x$ and $s\in \mathscr F(U)$, $j_x(i_x(s_x))=s_x$ by construction. On the other hand, suppose $(s_p)\in \mathscr F^+(U)$. Take a neighbourhood $V\subseteq U$ of $x$ and $t\in \mathscr F(V)$ such that $t_p=s_p$ for all $p\in V$. Then $i_x(j_x((s_p)))=i_x(s_x)=i_x(t_x)=(i_V(t))_x$. By construction, $(s_p)|_V=i_V(t)$ and thus $(i_V(t))_x=(s_p)_x$. Combining the two, we see that $i_x$ and $j_x$ are inverse isomorphisms.

Comment: Great, thanks a lot. By the way, I recently read siegfried bosch algebraic geometry and commutative algebra, I find that it sometimes prove too fast for me, could someone tell me which textbook you read algebraic geometry first, which pace will not such fast, thanks a lot.  You can think I have a knowledge for commutative algebra in the first part.